# Userform Combobox search but clear if blank

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, filter, combobox

I have a userform where the user inputs selection's from a dropdown box and once the command button is pressed it filters and sorts the sheet to show them just what is needed.

However, I'm struggling to find a solution which states if blank then don't apply any filter on that column.

Can anyone assist?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Employee List").Visible = True
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Employee List").Select

    Sheets("Employee List").CommandButton1.Visible = False
    Sheets("Employee List").CommandButton2.Visible = False
    Sheets("Employee List").CommandButton3.Visible = True
    Sheets("Employee List").CommandButton4.Visible = True

    Worksheets("Employee List").ListObjects("Employee_List").Range.AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=ComboBox1.Value, Operator:=xlAnd
    Worksheets("Employee List").ListObjects("Employee_List").Range.AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:=ComboBox2.Value, Operator:=xlAnd
    Worksheets("Employee List").ListObjects("Employee_List").Range.AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="True", Operator:=xlAnd
    Worksheets("Employee List").ListObjects("Employee_List").Range.AutoFilter Field:=30, Criteria1:="<=" & Me.ComboBox3.Value, Operator:=xlAnd
    Worksheets("Employee List").ListObjects("Employee_List").Range.AutoFilter Field:=31, Criteria1:="Yes", Operator:=xlAnd
    Worksheets("Employee List").ListObjects("Employee_List").Range.AutoFilter Field:=32, Criteria1:="No"

    Worksheets("Employee List").Columns("E:E").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Worksheets("Employee List").Columns("I:P").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Worksheets("Employee List").Columns("R:S").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Worksheets("Employee List").Columns("T:T").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Worksheets("Employee List").Columns("V:AF").EntireColumn.Hidden = True

    Me.Hide
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

Comment: Please be more specific what you mean by *"**if blank** then don't apply any filter on **that column**"*.

Comment: Hi @Pᴇʜ If the user doesn't want to apply a site filter then it will show all sites. The current code seems to hide them all.

Comment: What "site filter"? This word does not appear in your question. You need to be much more specific. Please read [ask] then [edit] your question. You will need more than one sentence to improve it ard make it more clear.

Comment: Sounds to me that you are trying to replicate the autofilter functionality. Why cant the user just use the filters provided in Excel instead of using a form to do exactly the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a simple If statement to check if the combox has a value if yes then set the table with a filter else omit the Criteria1 argument.

[More Information on Criteria1 Argument of Range Autofilter method can be found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.autofilter)

Try something like this:

```
If UserForm1.ComboBox1.Value <> "" Then
    Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter field:=1, _
    Criteria1:=UserForm1.ComboBox1.Value
Else
    Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter field:=1
End If
```